# Config files and Reltool

Tags: erlang

I'm building a release with Reltool. The app needs config files to start. It reads a config file using the following function:

```
read_config(Filename) ->
    {ok, [Config]} = file:consult(filename:join(
                                  [filename:dirname(code:which(?MODULE)),
                                   "..", "config", Filename])),
    Config.
```

What's a good way to use config files so that Reltool builds a working release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to have your own config file, unless it's for very special purpose.
If your config file is different from version to version, you can have those different config to your `<application>/ebin/<application>.app`.

You can setup your default config variables to your `<application>/ebin/<application>.app`. 
For more details about this, please refer to http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/app.html

Then, you are ready to use the config variables by using
`application:get_env(<application_name>, <key>, <default_value>)`.
If not defined, you can also set with `application:set_env/3`. 
For more, please look at this http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/application.html

Then you can also override those application variables by defining `<any_name_or_system_name>.config`, then use that one when you start with `erl` command with `--config <file_name>.config`. You can take a look at this for starting command options, http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html

When you start a command, you can also override the config variables by using `-<application> <key> <value>`.

You may also take look at this for config file syntax for your application.
http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/config.html

Once you have succesfully built an OTP application, it will seem very easy to you.

Comment: Excellent! I've brainlessly copied the config reading part from some webmachine demo code. But offcourse OTP has better tooling for this. Thx for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

In case you need more specialized config files `rebar` allows you to copy files into your release, eg. into a `etc` folder under your app (`rebar` creates `etc` by default) using the `overlay` option in your `reltool.config` file (`overlay` is not a standard `reltool` config option):

```
%% reltool.config
{overlay, [{copy, "../path/foo.config", "etc/foo.config"}, ...
```

You can pass the config file as argument to the vm using the `vm.args` file:

```
%% vm.args
-config etc/foo.config
```

Your start script should pass the vm.args file as argument to the vm (again `rebar` generates a script that does that automatically).

The function `init:get_argument` allows you to read more specialized arguments to the vm, eg:

```
%% vm.args
-very_special_config etc/foo.config
```

and

```
case init:get_argument(very_special_config) of
  {ok, Arg} -> Arg;
  _ -> fail
end
```

Comment: It's not `reltool` that allows you to copy a file into release but Rebar. The option `overlay` is not a standard `reltool` config option, see: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/reltool.html

Comment: @Amiramix Thanks, god catch! I fixed the answer. Cheers!